# "select is not valid at this position for the server version..." when subqueries are added

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a syntax error, and I don't know how to fix it. I'm kind of new to MySQL and the error message is just confusing me.

```
Select dept_name, total_student, total_instuctor, total_course
From department as d
    natural left join ( select dept_name count( dept_name ) as total_student
                        from student
                        group by dept_name) as s
    natural left join ( select dept_name count( dept_name ) as total_instructor
                        from instructor
                        group by dept_name) as i
    natural left join ( select dept_name count( dept_name ) as total_course
                        from course
                        group by dept_name) as c
Group By dept_name
Order By count( total_student ) desc;
```

currently getting an error message "select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : '(', WITH" the Select that is underlined is the very first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot all the `,` in the subquery selects:

```
Select dept_name, total_student, total_instuctor, total_course
From department as d
    natural left join ( select dept_name, count( dept_name ) as total_student
                        from student
                        group by dept_name) as s
    natural left join ( select dept_name, count( dept_name ) as total_instructor
                        from instructor
                        group by dept_name) as i
    natural left join ( select dept_name, count( dept_name ) as total_course
                        from course
                        group by dept_name) as c
Group By dept_name
Order By count( total_student ) desc;
```